# Tablesorter : how to ignore text in cells

Tags: jquery

When using tablesorter I cannot sort out properly when I add something to say a number in a table cell.
eg. 30 MB, 50 MB etc.

Is there anyway of telling the sorting to ignore text in a cell ie. the MB in this example?

Also, about in-line styling and tags:
How can I sort out the following properly?

```
<td><span>upto</span> 50 <br /> MB</td>
```

Taking into account the 'upto' and 'MB' text and the `<br />` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the textExtraction option to the tableSorter method.

Something in the lines of:

```
var extractData = function(node)  {      
    return $(node).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); 
} 

$(document).ready(function()     {         
    $("#yourTable").tableSorter( {
        textExtraction: extractData
        } ); 
} );
```

Link for DOC: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Check example @:http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html

Comment: Thank-you for this.  Where do I put it?  I want to sort out the column labelled 3 in the code below:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
            0: { sorter: false },
   3: { sorter: 'digit'},
   5: { sorter: 'digit'},
            1: { sorter: false },
   7: { sorter: false }
   
        }
  
    }); 
});

Comment: Thank-you.  Sorry for not replying earlier.  Its seems to work ok when applied to whole table.  I cannot get it to work for a particular column only and ignore the other columns.  Any ideas please.  Tried so hard to get the syntax correct.  But still does not work.

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using in the original question?

Comment: @ Cybernate Hi, thank-you.  Pls find the link below (I need the column 'age' sorting properly).  Much appreciated: <http://www.moneycheckerpen.com/test/test-tablesorter.html>

Comment: the link should be: [link](http://www.moneycheckerpen.com/test/test-tablesorter.html)

Answer (score 4):

I found the "problem" was solved in a forked/updated version of the tablesorter code hosted on the jQuery site.
The forked version is here:
http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Found another way of doing it: 
change the codes as follows:

```
<td>upto<br /><span>50</span>MB</td>
```

the apply the following text extraction:

```
textExtraction: {
        3: function(node) {
               return $(node).find("span:last").html();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As reported in other answers I'm using tablesorter [textExtraction feature](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html)

I found useful this *sort attribute* solution when dealing with table that have both complex and simple column markups:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node) { 
        // look for a 'sort' attribute in <td> element
        var sort = node.getAttribute('sort');
        if(sort){
            //use it for sorting if found
            return sort;
        }else{
            //default sorting behaviour if not found
            return node.innerHTML;
        }   
    }       
});
```